# How do I find the spectral radius of the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iteration matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbC93.png)

a)I need to find the spectral radius of the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iteration matrices from the given matrix.

I know that the spectral radius is the maximum eigenvalue however I am still confused by the question.

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Check wikipedia.

Comment: @Moo Yes thank you. I was able to find the spectral radius of the Gauss-Seidel Method however, i was not able to do it for the relaxation (SOR) method. Is there any chance you can help me with this?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to find the parameter $\omega$. Then using this result, find the spectral radius using the preconditioning matrix (where $D$ is the diagonal and $E$ is the lower triangular like you used in the GS-Method) $$\dfrac{1}{\omega}\left(D - \omega E\right)$$

Comment: @Moo I tried doing that however i did not get the correct answer. I worked out w to be 1.1716 however then when working out p I get 0.3719 which is incorrect. I know it is incorrect because the answer does not satisfy this equation: p = w - 1

Comment: $\omega$ looks correct, but the spectral radius does not. Let me take a quick look.

Comment: @Moo Yeah the spectral radius is also where I think i went wrong, thank you

Comment: $$msor = 1/w(D - w E), tsor =  ID[9] - inverse(msor) A$$ Then find the largest eigenvalue. I got the result $$\rho_{sor} = 0.17157$$

Comment: @Moo Thank you very much, you've helped me a huge amount!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

For the Jacobi Method, we have

$$mjac = \begin{pmatrix}
 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$tjac = I - mjac^{-1} A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues of $tjac$ are

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},0,0,0$$

The largest in absolute value makes the spectral radius of the Jacobi Method

$$\rho_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Can you do this for the Gauss-Seidel Method?